# Map array function/syntax problems

Tags: python, arrays, pygame

I'm working on a little python game for school, and I'm having problems understanding which syntax to use.

```
def draw_detail_from_array():
    for y in new_map_array:
        for x, _ in enumerate(y):
            if y[x] == "v":
                mapx = y[x].index
                mapy=new_map_array[y].index
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(pygame.image.load("grass1.png"), (32,  32))
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(pygame.image.load("grass1.png"), (mapx + 1) * 32, (mapy + 1) * 32)
```

So I have a 2d array and while I loop through it if there's a "v" I want it to put a sprite in the spot that corresponds with the location in the array.

The problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to get the index from the current x and y and use that to "blit" the sprite to the screen location (The array corresponds to a 20 by 15 grid of squares 32 x 32 pixel in size.)
The array is already filled randomly with "v" replacing the "_" that represents a blank space.

I've tried a few different methods on top of this and I feel stuck.Everything I try from memory gives me errors like:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

so I know I'm either not using the right functions or syntax or there is a larger overarching problem with the structure of my function. I'm still relatively new to python and this is exhausting me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `.index`? a property or a function

Comment: It's a function, I misread a forum post that I thought said it would get the index for the element and either it doesn't or I'm using it wrong, I really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply something like this:

```
def draw_detail_from_array():
    x, y = 0, 0
    for row in new_map_array:
        for col in row:
            if col == "v":
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(pygame.image.load("grass1.png"), (x, y))
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0
```

Note that you should not load the image over and over again; it's a major performance issue. Just load it once and reuse it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem, and I understand how (which is a nice bonus) I plan to add the "dirty rect" method detailed on the pygame site, is this what you were referring to? Or do you mean the use of pygame.image.load is unnecessary? If so what would be an alternative?

Comment: The problem is that every time you call `pygame.image.load("grass1.png")`, pygame loads the image from disk. If new_map_array has 50 `v` elements in total, it means that this loop loads the image 50 time from disk. Better load it once (like `grassimage = pygame.image.load("grass1.png")` and reuse it (so, in this function, use `DISPLAYSURF.blit(grassimage , (x, y))`).

Comment: That actually helped my framerate noticeably, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
mapx = y[x].index
mapy=new_map_array[y].index
```

Because `index` here is a function you must call it like this

```
mapx = y[x].index()
mapy=new_map_array[y].index()
```

If you leave out the parentheses, instead of the result of the function you will assign *the function itself* to `mapx` and `mapy`, causing `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'`

Comment: Thank you, so now I understand how the function works , but the overarching problem still persists, I think it lies in my whole structure of my function

Comment: @Tom I couldn't say, but that is out of the scope of this quesion anyway

Comment: How so? I'm asking generally if my method is unworkable, are there different ways to approach this problem?

Comment: Your question is about problems with syntax errors, this fixes that. Of course it's possible that there are problems with your approach but to 'solve' that we may need more detailed information, and that should go in a seperate question, I think.

Comment: Would you be able to kindly help me here? I've been trawling existing questions for over an hour before posting.

Comment: I would, but I have no experience with pygame